# interpret this algorithm of discrete mathematics and its applications, Kenneth H. Rosen

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Q. Describe an algorithm that inserts an integer x in the appropriate position into the list a_1, a_2, ... ,a_n of integers that are in increasing order.

A.

```
procedure insert(x,a_1,a_2,...,a_n :integers)
{the list is in order: a_1<=a_2<=...<=a_n}
a_(n+1) := x+1
i :=1
while x>a_i
i :=i+1
for j:=0 to n-i
a_(n-j+1) := a_(n-j)
a_i=x
{x has been inserted into correct position}
```

my question. why `a_(n+1) := x+1` ? and if the initial value `i=n` then `j=0 to -1` ?
do i exclude `j=-1`?
sorry for bad speaking please interpret this algorithm

Answer (score 1):

> why a_(n+1) := x+1 ?

This is [sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node)  approach.

Using this stop-element, one can use the same method for inserting x into any position of the list. Otherwise one have to look for whether list is finished and append x at the end with special piece of code

> if the initial value i=n then j=0 to -1 ?

It is implied that operator for `for j:=0 to -1` is not executed (some languages have special kinds of `for` loop for reverse direction like `for ..downto` in Pascal or `step` argument in some others)